# Running Jplayer from an SSL website, but the audio files are non-SSL. Audio files will not play

Tags: ssl, jplayer

I run a music aggregation website, HVmusic.com, where I use Jplayer to play MP3 files that users add to their listings. About a year ago I changed my site to run SSL (https) and now I find that any MP3 files that are hosted on non-SSL websites cannot be played by jPlayer.

Here is an example of the Jplayer code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){        // Player instance
        $("#jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: "http://ellywininger.com/mp3/Little Red Wagon.mp3"
                });
        },
    play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
        $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    },
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        swfPath: "/common/licensed/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        useStateClassSkin: true
      });        // Player instance
        });
</script>
```

Note that this person's site (http://ellywininger.com) actually runs SSL mode and the http: redirects to https:, so these MP3 files play fine in Jplayer.

Is that just the way it is? I didn't think these files were considered "part of the SSL page" but instead "links", and links from an SSL page can be to non-SSL pages.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "...and links from an SSL page can be to non-SSL pages..." No, they cannot, as that is considered insecure. This is called mixed content, and there is some analysis [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) of the relative hazards of various types of mixed content.

Comment: Yes, they can. You can have anchor tags linking to non-SSL pages from an SSL page and the page is still considered secure by all browsers. What you can’t do is include non-SSL content on an SSL page. 

That is the question I am trying to understand about Jplayer... I guess the MP3 files specified in the JavaScript are considered page content, but they could be considered **links** as anchor tags are.